# Javascript Button to run apex class

Tags: apex, button

I want create a custom button that runs an apex class.

This class create a record and open the detailed page of the record created.

Do you know if is it possible?

Do you have an example code for the button that exercutes the class? javascript?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.
BR.

Answer (score 2):

I think what your looking for would be either an [ActionFunction](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) or [VisualForce Remoting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm), the latter being more for Ajax without maintaining controller state.

You can chain together actions in an `ActionFunction` to invoke the correct redirects after a record is created, inserted, updated, etc.